# Can't receive more than one message using TcpClient and StreamReader

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader

I need to receive the second reply from a server application. When I connect to the server app for the first time I get a reply. But when I try to send another message, I can't receive it.

I've tried searching for a solution but I can't find anything. I believe the problem is the pointer on my reader is still at the end. That's why I can't read the next reply. Here is my code:

```
public static void XConn()
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",xx); // i cant show the IP sorry
    Stream s = client.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);

    String r = "";
    sw.AutoFlush = true;      

    sw.WriteLine("CONNECT\nlogin:xxxxxxx \npasscode:xxxxxxx \n\n" + Convert.ToChar(0)); // cant show also

    while(sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        r = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Debug.WriteLine(r);
        if (r.ToString() == "")
            break;
    }

    sr.DiscardBufferedData();

    //get data needed, sendMsg is a string containing the message i want to send
    GetmsgType("1");
    sw.WriteLine(sendMsg);

    // here i try to receive again the 2nd message but it fails =(
    while(sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        r = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Debug.WriteLine(r);
        if (r.ToString() == "")
            break;
    }

    s.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

Comment: protocol? what do you mean? do you mean the message sent?

Comment: Yes—what is the specified format of the messages sent and received? Is it supposed to be CONNECT\nlogin...\npassword...\n\n\0? Also, how is it failing—are you getting an error or is nothing being printed out?

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClient.GetStream()` returns a `NetworkStream`, which doesn't support seeking so you can't change the reader pointer, and as long as the connection is open, it's never really at the end, either. This means that the `StreamReader.Peek()` method might be returning a misleading `-1` when there is a delay from the server between responses.

One reliable way to get the response is to set a read timeout and just keep looping until an exception is thrown, which you can catch and carry on. The stream will still be available to send another message.

```
       s.ReadTimeout = 1000;

       try
       {
          sw.WriteLine(sendMsg);

          while(true)
          {
            r = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(r);
          } 

         sr.DiscardBufferedData(); 
       }
      catch(IOException)
       {
         //Timed out—probably no more to read
       }
```

---

**UPDATE**: The following may also work, in which case you don't really need to worry about setting timeouts or catching exceptions:

```
         while(true)
         {
           r = sr.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine(r);
           if (sr.Peek() < 0) break;
         }
```

Comment: ill try this one sir. ill give you a feedback later on. thankyou for the explanation.. the reason why i have that kind of a protocol is because its the requirement of a STOMP. im connecting to one of it.. at first when i try to connect then SUBSCRIBE it reply's a message..then like the code that i post above.. when i try to send the message(for example im getting a list of names), my codes just stops this part of the code ... r = sr.ReadLine();